# Store character in 2d array and print

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am trying to make a program that plays battleship. I have a 2D array that is printed to the console with nested for loops to display a 10x10 grid of dots that represent the grid. I would like to be able to have the user input an x and y coord for the ship and have it displayed on the grid with a different character like a "+" for example and have it stored every time I "re-draw" the grid.

`char playerBoard[][]` is initialized earlier in the global scope.

```cpp
void drawPlayerBoard()
{
    
    int yLabel = 0;
    char xLabel = 65;// ascii  
    


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            playerBoard[i][j] = 46;// ascii 
        }
    }
    
    cout << "   ";
    for (xLabel = 65; xLabel < 75; xLabel++)
    {
        cout << xLabel << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        yLabel++;
        if (yLabel >= 10)
        {
            cout << yLabel << " ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << yLabel << "  ";
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            cout << playerBoard[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Having to say "`char playerBoard[][]` is initialized earlier in the global scope." in a question is an admission of failure to produce a [mre]. If you don't have a [mre], you're almost always asking the question too soon.

Comment: Rather than `playerBoard[i][j] = 46;// ascii` write `playerBoard[i][j] = '.';`. Now you don't have to leave a comment and readers don't have to have the ascii table memorized. [In general, don't use encoding numbers where the actual value will do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this a lot easier on yourself. For instance, initializing every value of `playerBoard` to `'.'` can be as simple as:

```
std::fill_n((char*)playerBoard, rows * columns, '.');
```

You probably *don't* want to do that in the `drawPlayerBoard` function, because you'll erase your board whenever you want to display it. Make a separate function:

```
#include <algorithm>

const int rows = 10;
const int cols = 10;
char playerBoard[rows][cols];

void clearPlayerBoard()
{
    std::fill_n((char*)playerBoard, rows * cols, '.');
}
```

For outputting X-labels, similarly avoid using magic numbers representing ASCII values. For instance, you can write `char('A' + i)` to get the letter you want.

To manage your spacing, use I/O manipulators to control the output width. This avoids ugly code like you're doing with your `yLabel` tests right now. Simply use `std::setw`, and avoid cluttering your code with strings of spaces.

Putting this together:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void drawPlayerBoard()
{
    const int colWidth = 2;
    const int rowLabelWidth = 3;

    // Draw X labels
    std::cout << std::setw(rowLabelWidth) << "";
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(colWidth) << char('A' + col);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Draw rest of board
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(rowLabelWidth) << row + 1;
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(colWidth) << playerBoard[row][col];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Notice how you can now control the layout with those two "width" values. The most useful here would be the `rowLabelWidth` value, which effectively controls how much indentation your board has.

To test, just some simple driver code from `main`:

```
int main()
{
    clearPlayerBoard();
    drawPlayerBoard();
}
```

And you get the output:

```
    A B C D E F G H I J
  1 . . . . . . . . . .
  2 . . . . . . . . . .
  3 . . . . . . . . . .
  4 . . . . . . . . . .
  5 . . . . . . . . . .
  6 . . . . . . . . . .
  7 . . . . . . . . . .
  8 . . . . . . . . . .
  9 . . . . . . . . . .
 10 . . . . . . . . . .
```

Now you can write a simple function to add your ships:

```
void placeShip(int row, int col, int size, bool horizontal, char player)
{
    if (horizontal)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) playerBoard[row][col+i] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) playerBoard[row+i][col] = player;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
    char player = '#';
    placeShip(3, 2, 5, false, player);
    placeShip(2, 4, 4, true, player);
    placeShip(0, 9, 3, false, player);
    placeShip(6, 6, 3, true, player);
    placeShip(8, 7, 2, true, player);
    drawPlayerBoard();
```

Output:

```
    A B C D E F G H I J
  1 . . . . . . . . . #
  2 . . . . . . . . . #
  3 . . . . # # # # . #
  4 . . # . . . . . . .
  5 . . # . . . . . . .
  6 . . # . . . . . . .
  7 . . # . . . # # # .
  8 . . # . . . . . . .
  9 . . . . . . . # # .
 10 . . . . . . . . . .
```